# IIS background process

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis

I have IIS server which runs few WCF REST services I created.
Now I need to add some kind of process that will run on the server and do some work for me once in a while.

I guess the IIS should initiate some kind of a background process or something, but I'm not sure what is the technology I should use in this case?

Comment: If you search for "scheduled task" instead of "background process", you'll find dozens of questions on this topic here already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a scheduled task to run in background using Windows Task Scheduler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568736/how-to-set-a-scheduled-task-to-run-in-background-using-windows-task-scheduler)

Answer (score 2):

After reading at least three other similar questions, it appears the best practice is to avoid running background threads and allow a windows service app to do the processing.  You could drop rows into a database table or append a line to a file to start the windows service work.

See any of these threads...

[Can I use threads to carry out long-running jobs on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536681/can-i-use-threads-to-carry-out-long-running-jobs-on-iis)

[What are some best practices for managing background threads in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655012/what-are-some-best-practices-for-managing-background-threads-in-iis)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Windows Task Scheduler, as mentioned by others, you could also:

In your `global.asax` file, in your `application_start()` method, you can spin up a new Thread to do whatever you want, and shut it down in the `application_end()` method.

Comment: You would also have to configure IIS to not unload your app if it's been idle too long.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [window task scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can schedule a process to come to life and then check to see if any component has queued up work for it to do. The work could be stored in a file (which would need to be locked) or a database table (that's my preference).

Answer (score 0):

Windows Scheduled Tasks would typically be the way to do this.