# Communication between ASP.NET MVC and background process

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on a larger website, and i would like to make "long running" parts of the program run on separated thread.
But I am kind of torn on how to make this happen, and though I would ask if anyone have solved a similar issue. The reason I would like to this is because among other things I send emails to users and there a quite a few database lookups before the email is send, it would not be necessary to lock the user while all this happens. There are also other cases where I would like to wait some time to send the email, in case more emails are to be sending, and then combine them.

I have thought of 2 ways to do this:

1. Have a thread running that is started in application state, that
   then will run the backend processing.  This will enable me to send
   objects directly to the thread.
2. Have a program running on the side,
   and send data to it via a table in my database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a background process to do any heavy work that needs doing.  Do not do it during your action method and do not spawn a thread to do the work from your action method:  you risk spawning many threads if you get much activity at the same time.

I recommend using a Windows service for your background tasks if you can.  This way, it could run on another computer than your web application if the need arises.

Use a database to store information about the background work to be done, but do not use a database table as "the queue of work".  Use a proper queue for that:

- Amazon SQS
- Azure Message Bus
- RabbitMQ

So, your action method would put the data needed for the background task in your database, then would push a message on your queue saying to do the work.  Your background task would pop the message off the queue and access the database to get the work's data.

See:

- [The Database as Queue Anti-Pattern](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.ca/2012/04/database-as-queue-anti-pattern.html)
- [5 subtle ways you’re using MySQL as a queue, and why it’ll bite you](https://blog.engineyard.com/2011/5-subtle-ways-youre-using-mysql-as-a-queue-and-why-itll-bite-you)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend saving the 'work' to a db, and then having a service or job running that picks up on the work and does it. It is better from a security standpoint and you don't run into problems with trying to do long running tasks in the IIS worker threads.

[What are some best practices for managing background threads in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655012/what-are-some-best-practices-for-managing-background-threads-in-iis)

Comment: Yes this is what i through as well :D